# How to route all module of HMVC to single controller CI

Tags: codeigniter, controller, routes, hmvc

i use HMVC with CI last version andi want to route all module of HMVC to a controller CI

If i use

```
$route[‘admin/(:any)’] = “admin/”;
$route[’(:any)’] = “index/index/$1”;
$route[’(:any)/(:any)’] = “index/index/$1/$2”;
$route[’(:any)/(:any)/(:any)’] = “index/index/$1/$2/$3”;
```

is not a solution, because a url can have many segments

i want to route the controller, method, and all parameters, like this:

```
$route[’(:any)/(:any)/ *all parameters *’] = “index/index/$1/$2/ *array($parameters)*”;
```

or how can stop the route of HMVC, i don`t need the route of HMVC.

Pls help.

Thanks, Jhon.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need routing, codeigniter does this already.

From a fresh CI install, playing with the `welcome` controller:

```
public function index()
{

    $args = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc();

    echo "<pre>";

    print_r($args);

    echo "</pre>";

    // $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}
```

Visiting [http://localhost/codeigniter2.1.2/index.php/welcome/index/param1/param1_value/param2/param2_value/param3/etc]

yields this:

`Array

(

      [param1] => param1_value

      [param2] => param2_value

      [param3] => etc

)`

So you have your controller [welcome], your function [index] and everything after are parameters; no need to mess with routing.

---

You don't need to account for every possible parameter that might be routed.

You can use a route like this:

```
$route[‘admin/(:any)’] = “admin/”;
$route[’(:any)/(:any)/(:any)’] = “index/index/$1/$2/$3”;
```

Then every URL except `admin/*` will be routed to `index/index`. From that point, you can grab the parameters like I posted above or via `$this->uri->segment(n);` where `n` is the segment you want (so, `$this->uri->segment(3)` would return `$1` from the route above).

Comment: Stormdrain, I think you didn`t understand well my problem.

I use HVMC and to call a module i use this url
I need to route:

    domain.com/admin/login/sss   to controller(admin)/method(login)/params 
    domain.com/admin2/login/sss   to controller(admin2)/method(login)/params

.....

and “all” the other to a controller/methos/params

for example:

    domain.com/blog/show/2012/10/ASC 
 
route to

    Class index extend Controller 
...
public function index($blog, $show, $params = array($year, $month, $order, ... and others){
...
} 
=>  route to   index/index/$blog/$show/$params

Thanks, Jhon.